# How can I remove items from Set when uncheck a checkbox ?

Tags: swift, checkbox, set, swift2

**Hi guys. I have a tableView , which has one checkbox and one label in all rows.**

So I tagged the checkboxes with labels. The goal is to make a set with clicked checkboxes. But the problem is I've done the checking and adding in set part. But I couldn't do unselecting part. --> I mean if I click the checkbox two times basically I deselect it so I have to remove the item from set, But I could't solve it.

If you can suggest something I ll be appreciated. Thanks.

```
func yourCheckBoxClicked(cbx:UIButton){

    choosenSet.insert(self.tableData[cbx.tag])// this is the checkbox label which was clicked
    print(choosenSet)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve what you want:

```
func yourCheckBoxClicked(cbx:UIButton) {
  let picked = tableData[cbx.tag]
  if choosenSet.contains(picked) {
    choosenSet.remove(picked) // uncheck
  } else {
    choosenSet.insert(picked) // check
  }
}
```

Comment: Bro I think you re wrong, because I want my choosenSet to have all the choose items in it. I don't want a second set that have all the unchecked items ? Maybe I didn't get your answer ?

Comment: @BeTa sorry, I didn't understand you clearly. now I rewrite my answer. I hope it will help